# Prove the following is (not) a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X),(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ be topological spaces.

Is $\mathcal{O}=\{A\times B:A\in\mathcal{O}_X,B\in\mathcal{O}_Y\}$ a topology in $X\times Y$?

Apparently this is not a topology, and it violates the axiom of a topology relating to the finite/infinite union of open sets belonging to the topology $\mathcal{O}$. The other 3 axioms are quite obviously satisfied. I can't seem to figure out/make sense of why the last does not hold. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Take $X=Y=\mathbb R$ with the standard topology. Can you draw what the elements of $\mathcal O$ look like? What happens when you take the union of two general elements of $\mathcal O$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following image as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

[image]

Each of the red, blue, and green squares (assuming that their interiors are included in the implied sets) are included in your collection of open sets. But their union is not, since it is not a product of open intervals.

Answer (score 2):

If $A_1\neq A_2$ and $B_1\neq B_2$, then (in general) there won't be sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\times B=(A_1\times B_1)\cup(A_2\times B_2)$.